Scheduled Job not getting executed after DST
We have Job which runs everyday at midnight at 02 AM EST. Using @Scheduled annotation with cron Expression in Spring Boot based application. The issue is, Job was running fine until daylight saving time happened, after that it stopped executing. Just restarted the application last time when it happened.
Now the question is, is there a way to fix this and Job has to run at least from 2nd day of the DST change without restart. Changing the time is not an option for us.
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * *")

currently passing zone as JVM argument -Duser.timezone=America/New_York

your cron expression is set to run daily at 2 am. Daylight saving also happens always at 2 am. Just change your cron expression to for example 4 am and then you won't have any issues. I would however question the way you explained the problem stopped executing after DST - DST would only cause it to skip 2 am on one day but not continue skipping it. Also DST is on 3rd of November?

@JAsgarov, Yes, that was weird, it did not execute for three days after DST, so we did restart the application. It is fine on DST end, executed as normal(in November last year)
